# How to get access the inner contents of an object tag?

Tags: web-scraping

I am scraping some data from a legacy website and I need to get the data inside an object tag, in frames's inside. I am trying like this:

window.frames['example'].frames['example1'].frames['example3'].document.getElementById("idTagObject"). This works, I have the element's reference, but I can't access its inner contents. This object is referencing an applet I guess. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

It is possible to access such information?

example tag

```
<object id="idTagObject" clsid="blablabla"/>
```

Comment: Share the site to test from so we can give accurate feedback

Comment: @gordonturibamwe sorry, I can't do that, the site's private. Its from a company my company works for.